# std::Assignable concept

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/Assignable):

> The concept `Assignable<LHS, RHS>` specifies that an expression of the type and value category specified by `RHS` can be assigned to an *lvalue* expression whose type is specified by `LHS`.
>
> Given
>
> - `lhs`, an *lvalue* that refers to an object `lcopy` such that
>     `decltype((lhs))` is `LHS`,
> - `rhs`, an expression such that `decltype((rhs))` is `RHS`,
> - `rcopy`, a distinct object that is equal to `rhs`,
>
> `Assignable<LHS, RHS>` is satisfied only if
>
> - `std::addressof(lhs = rhs) == std::addressof(lcopy)` (i.e., the
>     assignment expression yields an *lvalue* referring to the left operand);
> - After evaluating `lhs = rhs`:
>
>   - `lhs` is equal to `rcopy`, unless `rhs` is a *non-const xvalue* that refers to `lcopy` (i.e., the assignment is a
>       self-move-assignment),
>   - if  `rhs`  is a *glvalue*:
>
>     - If it is a *non-const xvalue*, the object to which it refers is in a
>         valid but unspecified state;
>     - Otherwise, the object it refers to is not modified;

It took to my atention the self-assignment note.

If `rhs` refers to `lcopy`, means that `lhs` was equal to `rcopy` even before the assignment (because `rhs` and `rcopy` are equal by precondition, and `lhs` and `rhs` are equal too since they refer to the same object), so it should be equal to `rcopy` after that as well, since no assignment has taken place, and thus, the **unless** comment is completely redundant, isn't?

Comment: Also, for those who are interested, the wording is exactly the same in [\[concept.assignable\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.assignable).

Answer (score 4):

The self-move-assignment condition here only comes up if the left operand is an lvalue and the right operand is an rvalue and both refer to the same object.  So code essentially doing

```
x = std::move(x);
```

possibly via other intermediate references or ways of obtaining lvalue expressions.

The "unless" clause is saying that a type does not need to satisfy any requirement at all when the assignment is this sort of self-assignment. In particular, the self-move-assignment might modify the single object involved, or even exhibit undefined behavior.

This is okay because the possibility is one that shouldn't come up anyway in ordinary uses of `std::move` or other xvalues. Using an xvalue expression is expected to mean that the old value of the object is no longer needed for anything. Since the left side expression refers to the same object, that implies we don't care what happens to it either.

Actual code using the same variable on both sides like `x = std::move(x);` would be entirely pointless. And an xvalue should not be passed around to functions in general unless there's good reason to know that the object will not be accessed by other means (at least not in a way where the object's state matters) until after the object is given a new specific state, if ever - for example, it's known no other references, pointers, iterators, etc. to the object exist, or the code to which they were previously made available will not be used again in a way that would involve accessing the object. In the case of the Standard Library, that usual guarantee on xvalues is a reason for [[res.on.arguments]/1.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/res.on.arguments#1.3): when calling a library function, "if a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique reference to this argument."

On a related note, some classes provide more specific guarantees on the state of a moved-from object, instead of just the general "unspecified but valid" state. A class might guarantee that a moved-from object is always empty right after a move constructor or move assignment. But note if `x = std::move(x)` is allowed, it can't guarantee both that the left-hand-side now has the value that the right-hand-side previously had, and that the right-hand-side is now empty!